# How to distinguish between a click in LI (div) and a click on a A link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a link inside a LI element, such as

```
<li class='app-context-menu'>
   <a href="http://website.com" class='app-context-link'>http://website.com</a>
</li>
```

Right now if a user clicks on the LI element or the link, they get forwarded to the link.

What I want is that they get forwarded to the link only when they click on the link itself.

Any idea how to make that possible?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Very odd question, as normally one would want the entire menu item to be clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Move whatever padding you have on the `a` to the `li` instead.  Having it on the `a` makes its clickable area cover the li. So, the `a` should have `padding: 0;` (or be changed to `display: inline;`, as mentioned in another answer).  Then add the relevant padding to the `li`.  You'll also need to make sure the background color is given to the `li` or a parent element.

Answer (score 0):

With CSS what you can do is to force to **click twice** to follow the link inside a li or anyother element.
What you need is

1. `<a>` wrapped into an element wich has the attribute `tabindex` set.
2. `pointer-events` set to `none` on `<a>`
3. reset `pointer-events` to `normal` once wrapper has focus or has been clicked.

[**DEMO** with submenu](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/tqpFk)
basic HTML is :

```
<ul>
   <li tabindex="0">
       <a href="#"> link </a><!-- whatever, sub items, ...-->
   </li>
</ul>
```

basic CSS is :

```
a {pointer-events:none;}
li:focus a {pointer-events:auto;}
```

This works of course if browser understand `pointer-events` rule.

Comment: At least , if this is not what you look for, i hope you understand that links ... links you once you click :)